# C pointer and function pointer problems

Tags: pointers, function-pointers

My enviroment is fedora17 64bit
Pointer:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = (*int)(&a+1);
The value of *(p-1) is 5.
Assume &a is 0x7fffffffdf50.
I wonder know why (&a+1) is 0x7fffffffdf64 and why *(p-1) is 5? 

Function pointer:
Re-write 
void(*(*(fptr[5])(char*);
to
typedef_______?_______;
pf(*fptr)[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your pointer assignment as

```
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
```